# how to finding set of zeros of polynomial in two variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Consider the polynomial
$p(z,w)=a_0(z)+a_1(z)w+...+a_k(z)w^k$ where $k\ge 1$ and $a_0,a_1,..a_k$ are non constant polynomials in complex variable z. Then {$(z,w)$   $ \varepsilon$ $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C: p(z,w)=0 $} is

1) Bounded with empty interior.

2)  UnBounded with empty interior.

3)  Bounded with non empty interior.

4)  UnBounded with non empty interior.

how to look for for this problem?

plz help me

Comment: You could try some examples and check for some pattern, say $$p(z,w):=zw-z^2=z(w-z)=0\iff z=0\;,\;\text{or}\;z=w\implies V_P=\{(z,z)\in\Bbb C^2\}\cup\{(0,w)\in\Bbb C^2\}$$ with $\;V_p\;$ the zeros set of the polynomial. The condition that $\;a_i(z)\;$ is not constant in $\;z\;$ means that $\;z=0\;$ always brings a solution.

Comment: yes i have done it similarly, i conclude that set is unbounded clearly. Am i right?

Comment: and further it should have  empty interior

Comment: Yes, for one it is unbounded and its interior is empty, can you see?

Comment: yes it is. neighborhood of $0$ is not there for any $epsilon \gt 0$

Comment: Yes. In fact any point's neighborhood isn't fully contained in the set. If you know only one option can be correct, then by elimination you've already found the answer.

Comment: so 2) is answer